# Jupyter Notebook is not being opened in windows using Anaconda Prompt?

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

**1) I tried to open Jupyter Notebook in Anaconda prompt**.

**Ananconda Prompt:**

(C:\Users\sankarreddy\Anaconda3) C:\Users\sankarreddy>jupyter notebook

[I 21:24:52.854 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users\sankarreddy

[I 21:24:52.855 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels

[I 21:24:52.856 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8888/?token=fb39c20421e31cc66fddfd4fc00c7f64b8003bc53b83f461

[I 21:24:52.856 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).

[C 21:24:52.868 NotebookApp]

```
Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
to login with a token:
    http://localhost:8888/?token=fb39c20421e31cc66fddfd4fc00c7f64b8003bc53b83f461
```

**2) My default browser is Google chrome and every time when I try to open the Jupyter notebook, the following is the result.**

**Result in the Browser(Google Chrome):**

ERROR: Gateway Timeout

While trying to retrieve the URL http://localhost:8888/tree?token=4f3786890eceb91493af9bd6f4b07ae1ac6888c6172bbfca:

Connection refused
Your cache administrator is webmaster.

Generated Sun, 23 Jul 2017 14:01:21 GMT by 103.217.212.129 (Mikrotik HttpProxy)

**3) I interrupted the process using 'Ctrl+C'.. it displays as follows.**

[I 19:43:23.364 NotebookApp] Interrupted...

[I 19:43:23.365 NotebookApp] Shutting down kernels

I have googled about this issue, but had very little help which is of no use.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to open Jupyter Notebook in port 8888 as stated by the error message `While trying to retrieve the URL http://localhost:8888/tree?token=4f3786890eceb91493af9bd6f4b07ae1ac6888c6172bbfca`

But, when running Jupyter Notebook, there was an error message stating something else is running in port 8888 and it started the server in the next available port, which is 8889: `[I 19:26:39.239 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://localhos t:8889/?token=86664b50ba28f3bd3431554bc84d60d8bf4f3bf4209a4ecf`

I'm not sure how to identify **what** is running on 8888, but you should definitely access your Jupyter Notebook on localhost:8889 .

Comment: The above should get your access to notebooks. As for whatever is locking 8888, maye a previous attempt to bring Jupyter Notebook up? Manually killing the process, or a reboot, might help.

Comment: Your tokens seem different on both URLs, hence the refused access. And it still shows a 8889 port URL on your code block. If this is just a typo, maybe you could review the whole post to help us help you? Also, did you try connecting on 8889? Or pasting the exact URL (token and all) on Chrome?

Comment: Yes Sir, it was a typo. I have tried rebooting the system, killing the process manually and I have tried opening the url with 8889. But nothing did work.